# Controlling console sysout with waits/notifys/synchronization

Tags: java, multithreading, console, synchronization

Okay guys look, this a simple exame, that I made. I am trying to learn better synchronization, but I have one question here.. almost all times I get the result I want on console that is:

```
Here they go!...2001ms
Mares eat oats - t1  3001ms
Mares eat oats - t2  4001ms
Does eat oats - t1  5001ms
Does eat oats - t2  6001ms
```

but sometimes dont... I get something like this:

```
Here they go!...2000ms
Mares eat oats - t2  3000ms
Does eat oats - t2  3000ms
Mares eat oats - t1  4000ms
Does eat oats - t1  6001ms
```

can someone explain me? Maybe because I have 2 cores? i have window 7 intel corei5

if you guys need my code its here, its small , not to large guys..

http://pastebin.com/nLczry9R

just need a good answer, why is this happening, thanks alot guys!
wanna understand this a little bit more, thread synchronization.
sorry my bad english, thanks alot in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you synchronize the methods? If you do this, every time you call a method the entire class is blocked (onto wait()) from the thread monitor (because the Monitor is of the Useless class). Use instead `synchronize(b) { .... }` inside the methods u1 and u2. And "b" probably doesn't have to be "static".

Look at this [enter link description here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html) for better explanation.

I think your problem is because:

1. b is static
2. synchronized is onto methods instead onto the lock (or monitor lock) object
3. you call u.u2 two times, but the first time calls it frees all the threads blocked onto the "Useless" monitor. So there is a race condition and the first thread which wins could be t2 or t1

So try to:

1. change b to not static variable
2. use synchronize(b) {...}

Comment: thanks for your help mate, but I cant synchronized on boolean, I guess.. is giving me error.
and I change to not static, then tryed to run the program twice at almost the same time.. and on the second program i get the same problem like in 1/10 of times

Comment: what error do you receive? try to use the object Bool instead of primitive type boolean...